# Mysql search and replace second patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

What Mysql query will do a text search and replace in one particular field in a table?

For ex. in one fild in table i've got text:

```
"abc def XXX ghi XXX jkl"
```

How to repleace only second XXX???

Expected output:

```
"abc def XXX ghi YYY jkl"
```

Thank You for Your help!

Comment: So you always have the string in this pattern i.e. two XXX or you can have string with only one XXX ?

Comment: you want to replace only 2nd XXX or the XXX which is last from all XXX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something like this

You would want to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(YourField, SearchString, 2),ReplacementString,SUBSTRING_INDEX(YourField,SearchString,-1));
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/41627)**

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('abc def XXX ghi XXX jkl', 'XXX', 2),'YYY',SUBSTRING_INDEX('abc def XXX ghi XXX jkl', 'XXX', -1));
```

**Edit**

Your Update query would be

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET Column_Name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column_Name,'XXX',2) ,'YYY', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column_Name, 'XXX', -1));
```

Comment: Before i was using function  like this: UPDATE table_name set column_name = replace(column_name, 'XXX', 'YYY'); How should i use Your function?